# vagrant public ip not accessible

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have this config:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.56.101", :mac => "0022334455DA"
```

And after `vagrant up` ifconfig prints:

```
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:12:96:98
           inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:9698/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:1141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:861 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
           RX bytes:115407 (115.4 KB)  TX bytes:98490 (98.4 KB)

 eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:33:44:55:da
           inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::222:33ff:fe44:55da/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:319 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
           RX bytes:19236 (19.2 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

But I still can't access the server at `192.168.56.101` on my machine or any other on my network. When the config was `private_server` I could access the address from my machine.

ip route show

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
192.168.56.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.101
```

When the vm is running, VB network config shows two connections:

```
Adapter 1
Attached to: NAT

Adapter 2
Attached to: Bridged Adapter
Name: Intel Ethernet Connection
```

So I guess eth0 is NAT and eth1 is a bridged connection? the `Intel Ethernet Connection` is my ethernet cable connected to the router.

Also when I open network and sharing center, it tells me there is an unidentified network with 2 connections: `VirtualBox Host-Only Network` and `VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2`. Which is confusing as I actually set Vagrant to use a public network.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @Mr.T, yeah, I just used the correct network:
config.vm.network :public_network, ip: "192.168.1.12", mac: "001122334455"

Comment: For those who have a similar problem but with the Homestead flavor of Vagrant, here is what I found: https://superuser.com/a/1214376/74576

Answer (score 9):

Using *ifconfig*, I found that the netmask assigned to the guest machine differed from the host's bridged interface, so I had to specify it manually.  Once I did that, the VM was accessible outside of the host system.  Here's my Vagrantfile entry:

```
config.vm.network :public_network, ip: '172.16.35.51', :netmask => '255.255.0.0', :bridge => 'eth0'
```

Comment: Do you still have two interfaces set? Like eth0 with 10.0.2.15 and eth1 with a static IP?

Comment: Any idea why this happened ?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess from this little amount of information, I would point to the routing table... the 10.0.2.15 eth0 nic is transferring considerably more data.

Comment: How can I get more info?

Comment: `ip route show` from the vm would be a good start... then we need to know what these networks attach to: "10.0.2.15 is nat'd through the visualization software which is shared through the host which sits behing a router/modem and 192.168.56.101 is a bridged adapter connected to the router/modem" etc.

Comment: updated question